# RStudio installation not providing me with 'real' RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to install [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) (I'm already running `R-3.3.2` on Windows7) but each time I download the `RStudio 1.0.136 - Windows Vista/7/8/10.exe` and install (using default options), I get the same problem - RStudio provides me with an 'empty' and unresponsive shell of an RStudio window. Here is a screen shot[image]

I find this very unusual and have no idea why this is happening. Does anybody know what the issue is?

Comment: Do you download Rstudio from [this page](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) ?

Comment: Did you use the installer for the correct OS? The file should be called something like `RStudio-1.0.136.exe`.

Comment: Smich7 - yes, the download was from that page.
Christoph - Yes - I chose the windows installer and am running Windows 7.

Comment: You might try launching RStudio with a different version of R -- see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R for more details.

Comment: You may not be downloading it through the correct website. Your computer may also not be able to run the version. Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running the program in administrator mode, since it will read and write a lot of files to your system, it seems logical that the program has to have administrator knowledge rights.

Comment: This is not an answer and more of a comment. I understand that you do not have enough reputation to "comment" as of now. Would suggest to work on it first.